# Gradle suddenly got VERY slow for no reason

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I was making an android app using jetpack compose (I am new to this) and everything was very fine, all the projects even the large ones would take like a minute to build and run in emulator but the problem started since I used Glide library (To load images from web) So after implementing this lib to my project, Build time of the project jumped from 10-20 seconds to 9-10 minutes, I deleted the implementation of that library which was from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.bumptech.glide/compose/1.0.0-beta01 then I synced my project and the Gradle was taking so much time to build the project (Still 9-10 minutes)

I restarted system, relaunched the IDE, but still it wasn't building it under 10 minutes, I did a lot things like I changed things in gradle.property but still not working (I Tried every single problem that was kinda same on StackOverFlow but still wasn't  fixing my problem) So I just made another project (An empty jetpack compose test project) And when I want to run it, it will take 6-7 minutes! Just an empty one with no code (only has default jetpack compose Greeting() function) So I don't know what to do please help, It was working fine for like 2-3 months but this just happened after I implemented that Glide lib in the project...Does reinstalling android studio fix the problem?!

Also this is what is it in the build panel:
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 441 ms

> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect
> Task :app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6m 58s
32 actionable tasks: 32 executed

As i said, this one is an empty jetpack compose project and it is taking 7 minutes to build!

Edit:
So I just realised even stopping a gradle building task (Canceling building process) is taking much more time than before, now it is taking about 1 minutes to only stop the building but before it would take around 5-10 seconds... I made a new empty project (Jetpack compose) and I changed my gradle.properties to this :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
android.injected.testOnly = false
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
kotlin.incremental=true
kapt.classloaders.cache.size=5
kapt.include.compile.classpath=false
```

So nothing just chaged, Here's my other gradle files configurations:

build.gradle (my application) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

build.gradle (module: app) :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Comment: As multiple projects are affected it could be a general problem, e.g. with your SSD. Recent SSDs are pretty slow on writing. To hide this problem they use a certain part of the flash memory as single bit cell cache. This only works if the SSD has enough free space and enough unused time to finally write the cache to the slower multi bit cells. So may be you need not keep your SSD alone for an hour and/or free up some space.

Comment: I freed up the drive c on my pc and here's the result:

Gradle build finished in 4 h 9 m 57 s 641

Comment: I dont know why this happened suddenly, only thing i did was to 1. implement glide lib to the project and change sdk from 33 to 34

Comment: Is only gradle slower or also other applications and/or the OS?

Comment: No the app/os/emulator all are ok just gradle is slow, i didnt install anything so we cant say that there is a problem with my SSD, It just happened after i downloaded lib glider... how can i delete all this lib files from my hard disk driver? is there anyway to delete permanently all glider lib files?

Comment: @Robert i edited my post, will you see any problem in them? with all i've done with my gradle.properties, it just reduced 1 minute of build time (Built time of an empty project) :
Gradle build finished in 4 m 48 s 807 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 days of suffering the problem is finally fixed! The gradle build timer went from +10mins to "successful build in 2s" so the problem was solved just by updating the IDE and SDK build tools to the latest version...

Also thanks @Robert for taking the time to reply to my question.

> I live in a third world country and everything even google and all its services are filtered here, that's why I couldn't get the new update of ide and sdk.